# AngularJS 2 observables http change detection

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services, rxjs5, angular2-http

Not been doing Angular2 for long, so apologies if I'm not understanding observables correctly ... in a component I'm subscribing to getData which sits in a service class. What I want is for the http get to call and emit changes automatically back to the caller/subscriber when url changes (and maybe any other URL parameters for that matter). How can this be achieved? Am I not understanding observables correctly maybe?

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

    url: string;

    constructor(
        private http: Http
    ) {}

    getData() {
        return this.http.get(`${this.url}`)
            .map((res:Response) => res.json());
    }

    setUrl(url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With your implementation, `getData()` uses whatever value `this.url` holds **at the time getData() is invoked**. In other words, if you change `this.url` AFTER you called `getData()`, nothing will happen.

To do what you describe, you need to wrap the stream of different URLs inside an observable:

```ts
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
  // The `url` property is replaced with an observable emitting a stream of URLs.
  private _urlsStream: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  // The http.get() now gets its urls from the url stream.
  // Every time a new url is pushed to the stream, a new request is executed.
  getData() {
    return this._urlsStream.asObservable()
      .mergeMap((url: string) => this.http.get(url))
      .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }

  setUrl(url) {
    // Setting an url pushes the given url to the stream.
    this._urlsStream.next(url);
  }
}
```

This code is definitely more involved than the original version. I've added comments to clarify but if you're new to RxJS I highly suggest you spend some time [reading the manual](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html) and [watching some tutorials](https://egghead.io/technologies/rx).

You'll want to learn about:

- The different types of observables (I used a `Subject`, which is a special type of observable that can both emit values and be subscribed to).
- The different types of operators (I used `mergeMap()` to "project" one observable - the stream of URLs - into another observable - the HTTP requests).